# What does this mean /var/www/vhost~pment/includes when deleting a directory using mc?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, mc

Using midnight commander i was deleting a bunch of direcotires, when suddenly mc tells me that `/var/www/vhost~pment/includes` is not empty and then ask if i want to delete it recursibly

What scares me is that im not near that path

im in the development folder of a site and from there i execute mc, select all folders with insert (without exiting my `/var/www/vhost/site.com/development`) and then press f8

Why mc shows me this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nervermind, i just figured out that ~ is just to short the path

so /var/www/vhost~pment/includes actually means /var/www/vhost/host.com/development/includes